# Phonegap Build (config.xml) and iPad splashscreen

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, cordova, splash-screen

I'm trying to configure a splashscreen for a landscape mode ipad app using phonegap build. I used the specification  mentioned in phonegap documentation (https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml), however it doesn't seem to work. It seems to be a problem with the splashcreen tag, because the icons work just fine.

I'm running an iPad with iOS 5.1. Has anyone had a similar problem ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "com.myapp"
        version   = "1.0.0">

    <name>myapplication</name>
    <description>myapplication</description>
    <author href="https://www.myapp.org" email="my@app.org">myapp</author>

    <preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />

    <gap:splash src="gfx/ios/splashscreen_landscape.png" width="1024" height="748"/>
    <gap:splash src="gfx/ios/splashscreen_portrait.png" width="768" height="1004"/>  

    <icon src="gfx/ios/icon57x57.png" width="57" height="57"/>
    <icon src="gfx/ios/icon72x72.png" width="72" height="72"/>
    <icon src="gfx/ios/icon114x114.png" width="114" height="114"/>  
</widget>
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that height is 768 instead of 748 (no status bar), so i ended up with this tag in my config.xml:

```
<gap:splash src="gfx/ios/splashscreen_tablet.png" width="1024" height="768"/>
```

And the splashscreen_tablet.png, must also be rotated by 90 degrees. It should be a 768x1024 png. It works the same way offline webapps do.